# Can't remove a widget from admin

Tags: widgets

I've just updated to WP 3.6, and I have also just turned off network mode on a Wordpress website.

I cannot remove a widget I created.  It is a text widget.  I can't remove a search widget either.

I am logged into WP with the same username that create the widget.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean can't remove? From the admin? from the template/front end? Please provide more info.

Comment: Sorry, from the admin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This symptom was caused by the plugin "Widget Logic Visual".

Deactivating this plugin resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to reset your widgets running this code from your `functions.php`

```
     update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $null );
```

**WARNING:** this will totally reset your plugins so make sure you save any widget data/settings you need.

[[Source]](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/03/widgets-reset-wordpress-plugin)

The source article also list a plugin/ and better instructions.